# How to use Firebase phone number authentication in angular2 app?

Tags: angular

Since digits is deprecated and now it is Firebase phone number Authentication. Can any one tell me the complete procedure to use the same in angular2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems digits is deprecated in favour of Firebase Authentication as they say in their documentation:
https://docs.fabric.io/web/digits/overview.html

I would recommend you follow their advice and use Firebase Authentication:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/

Nevertheless, if the cdn you provided is still available, you could be able to use it. You can use any web library with angular2.