# Firebase authentication with Phone Number

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, angular2-routing

[Here is the description of phone authentication of firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/phone-auth)

Can anyone please tell me the complete procedure to use this in an angular2 app?
How to use recaptcha in this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Firebase phone number authentication in angular2 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258410/how-to-use-firebase-phone-number-authentication-in-angular2-app)

Answer (score -1):

**now phone auth is available in firebase.Here is Code for Phone Auth using Firebase:**

```
EditText phoneNum,Code;           //// two edit text one for enter phone number other for enter OTP code
Button sent_,Verify;                    // sent_ button to request for verification and verify is for to verify code
private PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken mResendToken;
private PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks mCallbacks;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String mVerificationId;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_phone_number_auth);

    phoneNum =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.fn_num);
    Code =(EditText) findViewById(R.id.code);

    sent_ =(Button)findViewById(R.id.sent_nu);
    Verify =(Button)findViewById(R.id.verify);

    callback_verificvation();                                




    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();



    sent_.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String num=phoneNum.getText().toString();
            startPhoneNumberVerification(num);                  // call function for receive OTP 6 digit code
        }
    });





    Verify.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String code=Code.getText().toString();
            verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(mVerificationId,code);                 //call function for verify code

        }
    });
}







private void startPhoneNumberVerification(String phoneNumber) {
    // [START start_phone_auth]
    PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    // [END start_phone_auth]


}







private void signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
    mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information

                        FirebaseUser user = task.getResult().getUser();
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sign in successfull", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        // [START_EXCLUDE]

                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    } else {
                        // Sign in failed, display a message and update the UI

                        if (task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException) {
                            // The verification code entered was invalid
                            // [START_EXCLUDE silent]

                            // [END_EXCLUDE]
                        }
                        // [START_EXCLUDE silent]
                        // Update UI

                        // [END_EXCLUDE]
                    }
                }
            });
}






private void verifyPhoneNumberWithCode(String verificationId, String code) {
    // [START verify_with_code]
    PhoneAuthCredential credential = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(verificationId, code);
    // [END verify_with_code]
    signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
}










private void callback_verificvation() {

    mCallbacks = new PhoneAuthProvider.OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks() {

        @Override
        public void onVerificationCompleted(PhoneAuthCredential credential) {

            signInWithPhoneAuthCredential(credential);
        }

        @Override
        public void onVerificationFailed(FirebaseException e) {
            // This callback is invoked in an invalid request for verification is made,

        }

        @Override
        public void onCodeSent(String verificationId,
                               PhoneAuthProvider.ForceResendingToken token) {
            // The SMS verification code has been sent to the provided phone number, we
            // now need to ask the user to enter the code and then construct a credential
            // by combining the code with a verification ID.


            // Save verification ID and resending token so we can use them later
            mVerificationId = verificationId;
            mResendToken = token;

        }
    };
```